# Eclipse Search Reference Across workspace

Tags: eclipse

I imported 5 projects into workspace. And some are api's and some are impl and some are gui applications. I want to search if say where a particular method or a class is referenced and used so that I can analyse the impact of change etc / investigate its usages.

I use the search functionality, Java Search (All references, within workspace) and it seems not to be able to search across workspace.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for references,
Put the mouse cursor on the class or method name in source code and hit `Ctrl+Shift+G`.

Or

If you want find a particular Java class or interface that exists in a project or library referenced somewhere in your workspace,use Open Type tool by hitting `Ctrl+Shift+T`

Hope it will helpful to you.